# Why I am getting UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

I m trying to run a [Spark maven Scala project](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark).

the `mvn install` didn't succeded (**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError**) :

```
   *** RUN ABORTED ***
  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
 at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
 at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:609)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canWrite(FileUtil.java:996)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:490)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:321)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:215)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:976)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:681)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:584)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:643)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:810)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:794)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1487)
```

I didn't understand the cause of the error since the Hadoop path is set and contains **winutils.exe** , and i have already run another java-spark project successfully ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added **hadoop.dll** To the hadoop path and the error disappear.